# ClassNotFound Exception: org.postgresql.Driver from [Module "deployment.ValidateUser.war:main" from Service Module Loader]

Tags: eclipse, postgresql, jsp, servlets

I am trying to connect with postgre databse with jsp program using Eclipse IDE,

I am getting this error:

> "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver from [Module
>   "deployment.ValidateUser.war:main" from Service Module Loader]".

I had put the jar files required for my project even though i am getting classnotfound exception error.

```
<%@page import="com.uservalidation.FarwordNames"%> 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<%-- Imports --%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.*" %>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*" %>
<%-- HTTP header --%>
<%response.addHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache");
            response.addHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
                response.addHeader("Expires","0");  

    %>
<%-- Variables that will be written --%>
<%
String fname = request.getParameter("fname");
String mname = request.getParameter("mname");
String lname = request.getParameter("lname");
String dob = request.getParameter("dob");
String addr = request.getParameter("addr");

    %>
<%-- Creating new staff account - writing --%>
<%
    try{

            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

            String conURL= "jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.157:5432/MIPSUITE_DEV";

            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(conURL,"mipsuitedev01","mipsuitedev01");

            Statement st = con.createStatement();

            //int status = st.executeUpdate("insert into users(fname,mname,lname,dob,address) values('"+fname+"',"+mname+"','"+lname+"','"+dob+"','"+addr+"')");

            /* if(status>0){
                out.println("Update sucessful");
            }
            else{
                out.println("Update unsuccessful");
            } */

            st.close();
            con.close();
            }

            catch(Exception e){
            out.println(e);
            }

        %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you are using eclipse, Right Click On the Particular jar where you put it in your project and go to Build Path and then click on Add to Build Path

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be fixed the problem by removing all resteasy/jaxrs/jboss libraries from the WAR file's `WEB-INF/lib/`.

Put postgresql driver
 jar files into `WEB-INF/lib` folder.

I think it's should be work for you.